# Profile Triangle Dropdown Text Spacing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The profile drop down that appears when you hover over the triangle next to your screen name has so much extra padding that it looks almost as though there is a blank line between every line of text.  The display uses about twice as much vertical space as the other SE sites do.

I think this should be tweaked to be more like the other sites.

Example:

[image]

Comment: It looks to have the same amount of padding as the other sites' to me. Using Security.se as an example. Is it possible if you could post a screenshot? Also what browser/ver are you seeing this in?

Comment: @jcolebrand thanks for the screenshot I'm looking into this.

Comment: I see this in Firefox 4.0.

Comment: @Jin you know I do Chrome, so there's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.